# Push notification is always null when I opened from killed app on IOS Flutter

Tags: flutter, apple-push-notifications, flutter-local-notification

I have a Flutter proyect and I'm using flutter_local_notifications. Everything is working fine, background notifications, when the app is opened. The problem is when the app is killed I receive the notification but when I click on it, this only open the app and when I check with didNotificationLaunchApp is always false. This happens only in iOS, in Android is working as expected.

How I'm validating? When the app starts I have the validation:

```
final NotificationAppLaunchDetails? notificationAppLaunchDetails =
  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();
if (notificationAppLaunchDetails != null &&
  notificationAppLaunchDetails.didNotificationLaunchApp){
Logic here...
}
```

Here is my AppDelegate

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import Firebase

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate, MessagingDelegate  {
override func application(
_ application: UIApplication,
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
 ) -> Bool {
FirebaseApp.configure()
Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate 
    let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
            options: authOptions,
            completionHandler: {_, _ in })
} else {
    let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
    UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
}
application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
 }
}
```

I read a lot of answers that I need this linein AppDelegate

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? 
UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
```

But didNotificationLaunchApp is always false